# What is the difference between DataStream and KeyedStream in Apache Flink?

Tags: join, streaming, apache-flink

I am looking in the context of joining two streams using Flink and would like to understand how these two streams differ and affect how Flink processes them.

As a related question, I would also like to understand how CoProcessFunction would differ from a KeyedCoProcessFunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `KeyedStream` is a `DataStream` that has been hash partitioned, with the effect that for any given key, every stream element for that key is in the same partition. This guarantees that all messages for a key are processed by the same worker instance. Only keyed streams can use key-partitioned state and timers.

A `KeyedCoProcessFunction` connects two streams that have been keyed in compatible ways -- the two streams are mapped to the same keyspace -- making it possible for the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` to have keyed state that relates to both streams. For example, you might want to join a stream of customer transactions with a stream of customer updates -- joining them on the customer_id. You would implement this in Flink (if doing so at a low level) by keying both streams by the customer_id, and connecting those keyed streams with a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`.

On the other hand, a `CoProcessFunction` has two inputs, but with no particular relationship between those inputs.

The Flink training has tutorials covering [keyed streams](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#keyed-streams) and [connected streams](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#connected-streams), and a [related exercise/example](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares).

Comment: Thank you so much David for the explanation. It makes sense now. 
I have a follow up question: How does scaling work in this case? Let's say there is a hot partition and the memory/disk cannot hold all the events, how will Flink ensure that the events are partitioned correctly to perform the join?

Comment: Thank you for asking about that in a new question. That way others can more easily find and benefit from the answer. I'll follow-up under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273158/how-does-flink-scale-for-hot-partitions.